# How do I take a substring of a string with multiple quotes? Rails/Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a string such as `(Shift opened: \"he clams \"sick\" but not sure\")` how would I extract just the part between the first set of quotes? I've tried combinations of split, slice and squeeze but always run into a case where it doesn't work. Thanks.

EDIT: The user inputs text, which can be in any form, so yes, someone could have an odd number of quotes. The text before the input is generated for record purposes. Some examples:

```
n = (Shift opened: \"he clams \"sick\" but not sure\")
n.split('"')[1] > "he claims "
```

If I could find the size of the array created by split I could do `split('"')[1..size-1]` but I'm not sure how to find that.

```
n = (Shift opened: \"\"sick\"\")
n.squeeze('"').split('"')[1] >> "sick"
```

That works fine.

This is more for error checking and making sure if people use quotes on input, it doesn't mess things up. And no I cannot edit how the string is generated. Hope I'm clear enough!

Comment: please post some attempts.

Comment: Also, if you can be more specific about the format of the input it might help... for example, are there always at least two quotes? Can there be an odd number of quotes? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the fact that regex is greedy by default, and use `/"(.*)"`, which will capture all text between the first and last quotes:

```
n = 'Shift opened: "he clams "sick" but not sure" some more text'

n[/"(.*)"/, 1]
# => "he clams "sick" but not sure" 

n = "Shift opened: \"\"sick\"\""
n[/"(.*)"/, 1]
# => ""sick""
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work. I've always hated regex's but I guess they have their uses...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to extract the text on quotes recursively and get something like this:

```
=> "he clams "sick" but not sure"
=> "sick"

or "lorem ipsum "xxxxx yyyy "alpha beta" zzzz wwww" dol"
=> "lorem ipsum "xxxxx yyyy "alpha beta" zzzz wwww" dol"
=> "xxxxx yyyy "alpha beta" zzzz wwww"
=> "alpha beta"
```

perhaps you will need a simple CFG:

```
S -> aS | a
a = /\".*\"/
```

or iterate the string stacking substrings on each quote